# r plotting error different number of rows with ggridge

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using ggridges I get this an error saying arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1536

Any idea what is happening?

```
Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1536

library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()



 packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘2.2.1’
> packageVersion("ggridges")
[1] ‘0.5.0’
```

Comment: I ran your code without errors and it created the plot. What version of ggplot2 and ggridges are you using?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Alright, I'm using the same version of ggridges, but version '3.0.0' of ggplot2. Have you tried restarting your r session in case there is some conflict with previous code you have run? If that doesn't work, I would suggest you update your version of ggplot2

Comment: that worked and updating rlang